# Symfony2 embedded form labels

Tags: forms, symfony, label

I have created embedded form for file upload, but when I add new file upload input element, it adds label "label__"

[image]

which is annoying, I would like to remove it. I have tried removing it from JavaScript by modifying code from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html, from

```
newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, ''),
```

to

```
newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__label__/g, ''),
```

But then it stopped working (only the last file was being uploaded). I can of course hide it with css, but I would like to remove it, or change it to something meaningful, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I changed this part of js to:

```
prototype = prototype.replace(/<label(.*)__name__label__<\/label>/i, '');
var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g,index);
```